# Dryer buzzing and greatly hot to the touch. What is wrong and what needs to be replaced?

Tags: electrical, dryer

I have a dryer in my downstairs basement that has had the heating element replaced in the past. After it was replaced it worked fine until after a cycle. After the cycle and about 30 minutes later it started buzzing quite loud and was very hot to the touch. I had unplugged it just in case, but I don't know what this problem could be, apart from a broken breaker that doesn't work or a broken heating element. What should I do make sure the dryer works correctly and safely?

Comment: "What is wrong and what needs to be replaced?" and "What should I do to ensure I don't plug it in again and start either a fire or severely damage the dryer?" are two different questions with two different answers, The second question's answer is: Once it's unplugged, cut the plug off and throw the dryer away. :) But I suppose that's not what you're really after, so that question is edited. Please edit again if you really wanted to ask something else.

Comment: Depending on the dryer, some of them are quite simple.  Usually just a motor to turn, the heating element, and controls.  Buzzing might be from wires shorting, very bad.  Can google the make and model to find instructions for repairing.

Comment: Heating elements do not buzz, they work or not. However the motor could buzz. It could be it just lost the start capacitor and will not turn. Check if it turns.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a dryer ... that has had the heating element replaced .... After it was replaced it worked fine until after a cycle. After the cycle and about 30 minutes later it started...

If you personally replaced the element, open the dryer up again and check what was done wrong. The replacement heating element probably had replacement instructions that can be perused carefully. A Youtube instruction video for your dryer type may help, or hire the dryer manufacturer's repair service to fix the problem.

If you had a repair person do the repair, have them come back and fix it. They may have done something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your duct is clogged and the lack of airflow burned up your first element.  Put the dryer on fluff and go outside and verify airflow.